# Finding the point of a set most close to the other set of points

Tags: machine-learning, distance, similarities

I've dataset that looks something like this:

```
Let us call this data "df"

ID var1  var2 var3 ... varn val
 1  v11   v12  v13 ...  v1n  v1
 2  v21   v22  v23 ...  v2n  v2
 ..........
 m  vm1   vm2  vm3 ...  vmn  vm
```

This data is divided into two parts based on "val" variable. That is if it's greater than threshold, it's "good", if it's less than that, "bad". Note that column "val" is only to identify the row as good or bad, and is removed from df.good and df.bad.

To use R notation:

```
df.good <- df[val>threshold,]
df.bad <- df[val<=threshold,]
```

Now, my goal is to find data points in df.bad that are close/similar to df.good.

This is how I'm doing right now.

```
 1. Take a point in bad.df. Calculate distance between that point and all the points in good.df
 2. Take the average of those distances.
 3. Repeat for all the points in bad.df.
 4. Sort average distance. Identify the ones with smallest distance as closest.
```

Now the problem with above approach is it's lot of time to get result.

My question is how do I get points that are close/similar to "good.df" in "bad.df" efficiently..

Comment: So, you want to find the point in one group which is the closest "on average" to the second group? Two questions arise. 1) Why that is huge task - do you have many many thousands of points? how much? 2) Do you insist on your definition of "closest" - i.e. the minimal (in group 'bad')_average_ distance from a point to points of the other group. Maybe you wish to prefer to replace the whole group 'good' by its single representative (centroid or medoid)?

Comment: You might want also to read about Hausdorff distance. It is among many distances computed b/w two sets. It isn't very fast to compute but you might like it.

Comment: Thanks for your points and questions. The problem is my dataset is 80,000x120, with df.good being around 1000... So it's actually 79,000x1000 computations... which my machine takes lot of time to compute. To your second question, i think it's worth to explore. I'll implement it. Will also explore Hausdorff distance Thanks so much!!

Comment: Found a link - https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/pracma/html/hausdorff.html